# Wordpress homepage 403 forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a WP site. It was working perectly fine untill recently. A couple of days back I moved the WP site inside a sub folder. Since then all WP pages load properly but the homepage shows 403 forbidden. Only home page shows forbidden. http://www.businessbid.ae/resource_centre/. The inner pages all load fine http://www.businessbid.ae/resource_centre/aa-2/. Looks like I have to modify .htaccess file but i am not sure about what i should modify. Could anyone please help me out with this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /resource_centre/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /resource_centre/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

/var/www/html/web/ is the servers root directory.

Comment: update your wordpress admin permalink.

Comment: check this codex..it might help you out:https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux, and you move the folder in a root user - then you might have to chmod the files again.Also make sure to check chmod on the subfolder as well!

Comment: Done. But that did not work for me. Thanks. Any other way out?